# Adding mixin to Angular host selector doesn't need !important

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have an Angular component button which use the class "button-custom".

`<button matInput class="button-custom">Test</button>`

With the style : button.component.scss

```
// SOLUTION 1 : need !important
.button-custom {
    @include button-custom;
}

// SOLUTION 2 : do not need !important
:host {
    @include button-custom;
}
```

And a global theme.scss :

```
// SOLUTION 2
@mixin button-custom() {
    .button-custom {
       ... my properties
    }
}

// SOLUTION 1
@mixin button-custom() {
       ... my properties
}
```

Solution 2 doesn't require !important on properties to work in contrary of solution 1. Why ?